# Program determines how many numbers are positive, negative, or zeros

Tags: python-2.7, loops

(Edit: Using python 2.7) I’m trying to get the user to input 10 numbers and the program needs to count and determine how many are negative, positive, or zeros.
However, everytime I run the program, it doesn’t give me the right number of negative or positive (or zero) numbers

```
i =[]
for i in range(10)  
    i = input('Enter Next Number: ')
    n = 0
    p = 0
    z = 0
    if (i > 0):
        p = p+1
    elif (i < 0):
        n = n+1
    elif (i == 0):
        z = z+1
print "The number of negative numbers is",n
print "The number of positive numbers is",p
print "The number of zeros is",z
```

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: You reset `n,p,z` to zero every time. Move that code to before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also want to convert the inputs to integers. If you really wish to add them to the list you will then need to iterate through the list after gathering all of the inputs. If retaining the values in a list is not needed @Bentaye answer will work just fine.

```
i =[]
n = 0
p = 0
z = 0
for num in range(10):  
    x = int(input('Enter Next Number: '))
    i.append(x)
for y in range(len(i)):
    if (i[y] > 0):
        p = p+1
    elif (i[y] < 0):
        n = n+1
    elif (i[y] == 0):
        z = z+1
print ("The number of negative numbers is",n)
print ("The number of positive numbers is",p)
print ("The number of zeros is",z)
```

Comment: I see you are using 2.7. Don't need the parenthesis in the print statements in the code I posted. Not sure about the int conversion on the input.

Comment: Yess, your solution worked the other one didn’t idk why. But thankyou !!

Comment: @Help If this answered your question please accept this as answered.

Answer (score 2):

As `Johnny Mopp` suggested in his comment, you need to declare your counters outside of the loop. If you declare them inside, they are reset at every iteration and you are only counting the last number input by the user

```
n = 0
p = 0
z = 0

for i in range(10):
    i = input('Enter Next Number:')
    if (i > 0):
        p = p+1
    elif (i < 0):
        n = n+1
    else:
        z = z+1

print "The number of negative numbers is",n
print "The number of positive numbers is",p
print "The number of zeros is",z
```